# How to compare 2 rows with same indices and drop one based on a certain condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 4 different dfs named: `X`, `step25`, `step26` & `step27`

`X` is my main df and is of shape(155854, 4) and the other 3 dfs are created from the `X` dataframe as follows:

```
X = data.loc[:, ['ContextID', 'BacksGas_Flow_sccm', 'StepID', 'Time_ms', 'Time_Elapsed']]
step25 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ContextID', 'BacksGas_Flow_sccm', 'StepID', 'Time_ms'])
step26 = step25.copy()
step27 = step25.copy()

for _, group in df.groupby('ContextID'):
    step25 = step25.append(group[group.index.get_loc(group[group.StepID.eq(24)].index[0]):][group.StepID.eq(1)])
    step26 = step26.append(group[group.index.get_loc(group[group.StepID.eq(24)].index[0]):][group.StepID.eq(2)])
    step27 = step27.append(group[group.index.get_loc(group[group.StepID.eq(24)].index[0]):][group.StepID.eq(3)])
```

This gave me the other 3 dfs and their shapes are:

```
step25 (2978, 5)
step26 (4926, 5)
step27 (11810, 5)
```

All these three dfs have a column named `StepID`, and their values are 1, 2, 3 respectively, so, I replaced them with 25, 26, 27 and then concatenated all the dfs `X`, `step25`, `step26` & `step27` as follows:

```
step25['StepID'] = 25
step26['StepID'] = 26
step27['StepID'] = 27
united_data = pd.concat([X, step25, step26, step27], sort=True)
```

Now, in the `united_data` there are values that have the same index.
For example:

```
        BacksGas_Flow_sccm ContextID  StepID  Time_Elapsed         Time_ms
104082            1.757812   7325335       3       153.238 08:49:06.900000
104082            1.757812   7325335      27       153.238 08:49:06.900000
205388            1.757812   7324656       2         145.9 07:16:31.660000
205388            1.757812   7324656      26         145.9 07:16:31.660000
105119            1.953125   7290176       1       139.695 09:30:39.170000
105119            1.953125   7290176      25       139.695 09:30:39.170000
```

What I would like to do now is to check which rows have the same indices and then only keep the row which have the `StepID` as 25, 26, 27 and drop or delete those rows whose `StepID`s are 1, 2, 3, and all the other rows whose indices are not duplicates must remain.

So, the **desired output** would be:

```
       BacksGas_Flow_sccm ContextID  StepID  Time_Elapsed         Time_ms
104082            1.757812   7325335      27       153.238 08:49:06.900000
205388            1.757812   7324656      26         145.9 07:16:31.660000
105119            1.953125   7290176      25       139.695 09:30:39.170000
```

and the **deleted or dropped** rows would be:

```
       BacksGas_Flow_sccm ContextID  StepID  Time_Elapsed         Time_ms
104082            1.757812   7325335       3       153.238 08:49:06.900000
205388            1.757812   7324656       2         145.9 07:16:31.660000
105119            1.953125   7290176       1       139.695 09:30:39.170000
```

Comment: If not duplicated index whats happen?

Comment: The values that are not duplicated must be there. They must not be deleted from the `df` named united_data

Comment: Is  for each group is only one 25 or 26 or 27 value ?

Comment: No, there are multiple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think simpliest solution is remove `X` from `concat`:

```
united_data = pd.concat([step25, step26, step27], sort=True)
```

---

I believe here should be possible use only [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['StepID'].isin([25,26,27]) & united_data.index.duplicated(keep=False)]
print (df1)
        cksGas_Flow_sccm  ContextID  StepID  Time_Elapsed          Time_ms
104082          1.757812    7325335      27       153.238  08:49:06.900000
205388          1.757812    7324656      26       145.900  07:16:31.660000
105119          1.953125    7290176      25       139.695  09:30:39.170000
```

Comment: Heck, an answer from top1 `pandas` answerer appeared in [Low Quatity Posts Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23040175).

Comment: Ya, thinking about it.

Comment: Hey, @jezrael, the previous solution of yours `df1 = df[df['StepID'].isin([25,26,27]) & united_data.index.duplicated(keep=False)]` worked for me. I had to do a bit of change in my data and that solution did work. If you can edit your solution back to the old one, I can accept your answer :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are only changing the `StepID` column. In that case, in would probably simpler to change it directly without concatenating anything:

```
step25['StepID'] = 25
step26['StepID'] = 26
step27['StepID'] = 27
united_data = X.copy()     # unsure whether useful or not

for step in [step25, step26, step27]:
    united_data[step.index, 'StepID'] = step.StepID
```